# How to display Distinct Count in Access Textbox?

Tags: sql, vba

This seems like it should be a relatively straightforward task but I've tackled it a few different ways with no luck so far.

I have two tables : People and Addresses.  I have a form with a recordsource that is a query joining these two tables. What I want to do is have the header display **"The database currently contains [txtPersonCount] people at [txtAddressCount] addresses."**

Since person key and address key are distinct within their respective tables my first thought was simply to set the controlsource of the textboxes to `=Count([tblPeople].[PersonID])` and `=Count([tblAddress].[AddressID])`.

Oddly, the count of address ID appears in both textboxes with this method. I assume what's happening is rather than counting the IDs from the respective tables, the IDs are being counted from the query behind the form's recordsource (for which there are more addresses than people, so it would make sense).

I then attempted to basically do the same thing by declaring my SQL queries as a string :

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT COUNT(tblPeople.[PersonID]) FROM tblPeople;"

Forms![frmBrowse].[txtPersonCount].ControlSource = sql
```

But that only ends up making the textbox display the text of the query.  Changing the string to be `"=SELECT COUNT...."` makes no difference.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: execute the sql on a ADODB recordset and pass recordset as the controlsouce because i dont think evaluate() will work here

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Any links you can suggest so I can learn how?

Answer (score 1):

You have created your SQL string but until you execute it or bind it to a record set you will not be able to use the results.

```
'Create a connection to your database
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()

'Create a record set that will let you access values from your query
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT COUNT(tblPeople.[PersonID]) as NumOfPeople FROM tblPeople;")

'You don't want to change the control source because that is the property of where the value will be stored.  You want to change the value of the text box.
Forms![frmReports].[Text144] = rs!NumOfPeople

'Close the connection and recordset
rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly! Not only that but appreciate the clear and well explained comments so I'll be able to replicate this for other uses in the future. Thanks so much for the help. Tried to upvote you but it says I need 15 rep. Will make sure to come back and upvote when I'm able to.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply  use a `DCount("*","People")` function on the People table,
and `DCount("*","Addresses")` on the Adresses table. Seems to me faster and more sensible than trying to make a DISTINCT COUNT on a JOIN.
If you really want a DISTINCT COUNT, you will have to use a tricky Crosstab query.
I posted something [here](http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2012/05/simuler-un-count-distinct-avec-access.html) (in French) and Roger's Access blog compared [4 ways to do this](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2012/06/count-distinct-in-access-part-4.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243791%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that loops through the selected records based on your parameters from the `Select` statement.  It uses the .RecordCount off a recordset, but the kicker is the recorde must be accessed first (hence the loop).